# Locating two Array images that are equal

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
function randomImg1() {
   var myImage1 = 
      ["img/10_of_clubs.png",
      "img/2_of_clubs.png"];
   var myImage2 = 
      ["img/10_of_clubs.png",
      "img/2_of_clubs.png"];
}
```

Above is a code for a game I created where if the user clicks on the shuffle button, it shuffles the images and a random image shows up. But I want to create another button where If the user clicks on it, an alert message appears saying if the two cards match or do not match.

```
function snapFunction(myImage1, myImage2) {
   for(var i = randomImg1.length; --i;) {
      if(myImage1[i] === myImage2[i])
          alert("Match!");
   }
   alert("Do not match!");
}
```

I tired to add this code into my website, but it doesn't work and only the alert message for "Do not match!" keeps appearing every-time I click the button.

Comment: Please be more specific (like add error logs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this example accomplishes what you're after.  Ultimately you have two identical image arrays so you really only need one.  What you need is two random values from that single array and to test if they're the same value.  So in this example there's a shuffle button with a click listener that pulls two random values from the images array, loads the images on screen, tests if they're the same, and provides a visual result on screen.  You could easily change that result to an alert, I just get tired of closing those windows.

The CSS I added is not important, just there to make the example look a little nicer.

```js
var myImages = 
    ["http://fillmurray.com/100/100",
    "http://fillmurray.com/125/125",
    "http://fillmurray.com/150/150"];
var shuffle = document.getElementById('shuffle');
var img1 = document.getElementById('img1');
var img2 = document.getElementById('img2');
var result = document.getElementById('result');
var msg = "";

shuffle.onclick = function() {

   var rand1 = myImages[Math.floor(Math.random()*myImages.length)];
   var rand2 = myImages[Math.floor(Math.random()*myImages.length)];

   img1.innerHTML = "<img src='"+rand1+"'/>";
   img2.innerHTML = "<img src='"+rand2+"'/>";
    console.log(rand1 + " " + rand2);
   if (rand1 == rand2) {
     msg = "Images Match!";
   } else {
     msg = "Images Do Not Match!"
   }

   result.innerHTML = msg;
};
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: center;
 }
.wrapper div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 150px;
  min-height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="img1">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="img2">&nbsp;</div>
    <button id='shuffle'>Shuffle</button>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work properly. It stays "Images Do Not Match!", even though the two images do match.

Comment: it actually is working it's just that the fillmurray website that is providing the images is using the same image for a couple of the different sizes.  for instance the 102px image and the 104px image are the same (one just slightly larger) that's why it's saying they don't match. They are in fact different images, just the same picture of Bill.  I put the file names to the console log so you can see the diff.

Comment: I also updated to use a larger variance in the image sizes in the example so it would be more obvious.

Comment: I want another button to find the matching cards, how would you do it?

Comment: That would be the topic of another question.  If what I've given you answers your initial question, please accept the answer, and post the next topic as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear out your objectives and get along with the JS syntax.

[See here how you declare an array.](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)
[See here how you call a function by pressing a button.](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)

Anyway, your function will just determine if the two strings that you are storing are equal, so the name of the images, not the images itself.

If you want to do just that, I don't see the need for arrays then..